# Image Upload and Retrieval from S3 Using AWS API Gateway and Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload the image to the s3 through lambda function by API gateway, but i am getting access denied for aws-sdk, even after allowing all the resources and objects in s3 bucket policies

This is the error when i am hitting the API in postman:

```
"errorType": "AccessDenied",
"errorMessage": "Access Denied",
"code": "AccessDenied",
"message": "Access Denied",
"region": null, "time":
"2020-06-24T11:23:45.234Z",
"requestId": "B1DAB104390AA77A",
"extendedRequestId":"kg5G6nagSdiU3MJAmjiJ3/BtBa9S/MLH3/R7NKn0brhjxARylUFfPXz/aNdhzsoiDWwhxH41bNQ=", 
statusCode": 403,
"retryable": false,
"retryDelay": 50.02802697429472,
"stack": [ "AccessDenied: Access Denied", " at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:816:35)", " at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)", " at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)", " at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)", " at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)", " at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)", " at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10", " at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)", " at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)", " at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
```

Comment: Have you enabled your Lambdas IAM role to have write access to the S3 bucket?

Comment: Yes, attached the lambda role and gave full access to the s3           {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Uploading images (and files) via the API Gateway is not recommended unless you are 100% sure you will be below size limit. 

Warning currently:
- API Gateway has a payload limit of 10 MB
- Lambda has an invocation payload (request and response) limit of 6 MB

The best approach is requesting a S3 Post signed URL and the Post the file on that URL directly into the S3 bucket.

here is a example from AWS Developer advocates : https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-workshop-innovator-island/blob/master/1-app-deploy/sam-app/getUploadURL/app.js